# Java NamedQuery and set date as parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, hql

I've created simple @NamedQuery in Entity:

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = ProductChangeLog.GetByDate, query = "From ProductChangeLog where date = :date ")
})
```

date is a Date.sql

And i want to execute this query:

```
List<ProductChangeLog> productChangeLogs = session.getNamedQuery(ProductChangeLog.GetByDate)
            .setString("date", date)
            .list();
```

My problem is, that this @NamedQuery produce query:

```
Hibernate: select productcha0_.id as id21_, productcha0_.availible as availible21_, productcha0_.category as category21_, productcha0_.date as date21_, productcha0_.description as descript5_21_, productcha0_.name as name21_, productcha0_.partnerId as partnerId21_, productcha0_.price as price21_, productcha0_.producent as producent21_, productcha0_.productId as productId21_, productcha0_.productUrl as productUrl21_, productcha0_.status as status21_ from ProductChangeLog productcha0_ where productcha0_.date=2014-01-20
```

And this query is wrong, cose date should be in "", like this: productcha0_.date="2014-01-20"

What should i do ?

I've tried

```
.setDate("date", date)


.setParameter("date", date)
```

and it sill doesn't works.

Comment: Could u post any stack trace? Did u miss `SELECT` key word in query?

Comment: It's HQL, i don't have to add SELECT.

Comment: There is no stack trace - i have no results for this query.

Comment: what is datatype of date variable ?

Comment: if ProductChangeLog table's date filed is datetime then you have to pass date object

Comment: its a date field, not datetime

Answer (score 1):

Is the date field in your ProductChangeLog pojo annotated with the correct Temporal?

[Hibernate Annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-property)

"In plain Java APIs, the temporal precision of time is not defined. When dealing with temporal data you might want to describe the expected precision in database. Temporal data can have DATE, TIME, or TIMESTAMP precision (ie the actual date, only the time, or both). Use the @Temporal annotation to fine tune that."

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Temporal(TemportalType.TIME)
```

Comment: I've added it, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you `=` operator, `parameter date` must be same the date form DB, exactlly. I think, it is like a risk using `=` operator for date parameter in `JPQL` or `hql`.
I suggest to use `>` or `<` or `BETWEEN`operator.

```
WHERE Adate > Bdate                     => Adate is before Bdate
WHERE Adate < Bdate                     => Adate is after Bdate
WHERE Cdate BETWEEN Adate AND Bdate     => Cdate is between Adate and Bdate
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to have no space between ":" and "=". So it should read

```
 @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = ProductChangeLog.GetByDate, query = "From ProductChangeLog where date =:date ")
})
```